# SSIS connection manager Expression not updated with the modified values

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

Connection manager in my SSIS package uses expression for connection string.
Expression contains user id and password variables.
My user id and password has encrypted values taken from config.In design time to avoid connection error I directly edited password variable's value with the actual password(decrypted)

The problem is **the connection string is not updating with the modified variable values**.
Any idea on this?

Comment: What is the package/project protection level? Is this a project level connection manager or package level?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a package configuration issue.

If you have a Package configuration set it will always use it regardless of whether you overwrite manually, as soon as you run the package it will use the configuration.

You will see an informational message in the "Error list" window if a configuration is being used.

If this is the case you will need to either disable the config or update it.